# How simple clic or long clic whit a custom adapter?

Tags: android

I have a custom adapter and in my maiActivity I have elementosList charged with a custom adapter and I have my code:

```
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String elementoSeleccionado = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Boolean realizado = getRealizadoPorElemento(elementoSeleccionado);
            if (realizado == true){
                actualizaRealizado(elementoSeleccionado,"N");

          elementosList.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            }else if (realizado == false){
                actualizaRealizado(elementoSeleccionado,"S");
                elementosList.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3DF400"));
            }
        }
    };
    elementosList.setOnItemClickListener(listener);

    //Long clic
    elementosList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            elementoSeleccioando = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

But it is not working.

I need implement some on my custom adapter to the click? or is here the error?

Comment: which part is not working?

Comment: The clicks, It not doing click or long click, I try to click but I do not nothing

Comment: Well, you are doing nothing in the longClickListener, so that's ok. If you want to modify the background of a cell of your listview, you should create a custom adapter. As this, you can have misbehaviours if you have headerviews in your listview

Comment: I have a Custom adapter!, my question is how use this clic methods, because, the method 
actualizaRealizado(elementoSeleccionado,"N");
Is not working, because is not doing the click.

And with the long clic I have an Alert dialog called down, and it is not showing.

My main Problem is that it is not clicking, in other Activity I have a similiar code but whit an ArrayAdapter and it work without problems.

Comment: There is no obvious link between click listeners, which are put on listview, and a list adapter. Can you post more of your code to try to see something?